# Using Thread in a window 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Is there a way to use the Thread class inside a ***No-Longer-Named-Metro*** application?

I'm trying to write a timer class with a "TimeLeft" property and can't understand how to accomplish this using Tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) class to accomplish doing timer.

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;

...
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, object e)
{
    // do somthing
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, but how would you suggest displaying the TimeLeft property? Wrap the dispatcher in a class with a TimeLeft property and updating it with the the time that passed since the start of the Timer?

Comment: You can update the UI from the OnTimerTick method, whether accessing a TextBlock directly or via binding does not matter. See [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick.aspx) on the Tick event for more info about keeping time left accurate.